# Why does this code NOT print "Instance of 'Future<String>'" since the Future delays the result with 2 seconds and stream Duration is 1 second?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, stream, future

I am playing around with async Dart and I was wondering how come this code works correctly, meaning it prints the text on screen when it shouldn't according to my understanding.

```
void main() {
  Stream stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1));
  stream.listen((event) async {
    getName('Kushtrim').then(print);
  });
}

Future<String> getName(String name) async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => '$name but HOMO SAPIENS');
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in more details why you don't think the code should work? From my perspective I can't really see any reason why it should not work and I don't know what you are confused about so can't really provide much explanation.

Comment: You seem to think that the delayed future, a `Future<String>`, turns into its value after two seconds, becoming a `String`. (Otherwise why would the timing change what it prints.)
That's not what happens. The future stays a future, it calls its `then`-callback when it completes. So the stream events run their `onData` callback, which each call the `getName` function, which returns a future which will (through some steps) complete after two seconds. At that point the `.then(print)` takes effect, and calling `print` with the string value. You get prints every 1 second, starting at 3.